# Have anyone seen mouse's click button only works when pressed in certain spots or held down for a long time?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I have had the Logitech M500 mouse for about 2 years. I play games so I do use the buttons quite frequently.

Today during a game, the mouse had no problems until a bunch of weird things all happened at about the same time. I am not sure if they are related to the mouse's malfunction but just in case they are, here are the progression of events:

1. Suddenly, I noticed for some reason I cannot issue a shift+enter command. The command appears as if I only pressed enter.
2. I noticed I had Team Viewer still open so I alt-tabbed out of the game and closed it because sometimes the commands can get messed up (it hasn't in all the times I left Team Viewer open).
3. Shift+enter command now works.
4. I noticed the right-click button suddenly does not work consistently. It does work if I pressed it down for a longer time (about 2 seconds versus the usual split of a second).
5. Later, I noticed if I press on the right-click button at specific spots it still works as usual (responds when pressed for a split second). See image below for approximate locations. Note: the right-click always works if I simply hold it down for a longer time.
6. I changed to another wireless mouse and it works perfectly so I know it is just the mouse. I am aware that it is probably just bad but I do hope the weird observations can still salvage it somehow.

[Image of the mouse with locations on the RMB marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kMvl.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

time for a new mouse perhaps. Does it do it in all programs or just team viewer ?

Comment: It behaves like this in all programs, on the desktop, or otherwise. The weird thing is why does it still work when I press it in certain spots?

Comment: its worn out, I have had the same once and ended up replacing it. Because somehow the pressure wasn't right. it would click in on right but not the left and had to press really hard to get it to click. Try another mouse and see, or open up the mouse and see if something is stuck underneath the clickers maybe some cleaning may do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I opened up the mouse and it does seem the RMB is not clicking as well as the LMB. I now simply have it not as tightly fastened and it is working like a charm for some reason lol. I will just keep using it until it finally gives up to the point that I must replace it.